# How do I view the TCP Send and Receive Queue sizes on Windows?

Tags: networking

Linux netstat shows send and receive queue sizes.

How do I get this info under Windows, specifically Server 2003?

Comment: I need the Recv-Q and Send-Q columns from netstat. see http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-netstat.html

Answer (score -1):

If all else fails try [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/about.html)

Comment: How is that going to tell me how much data is sitting in a TCP buffer?

Comment: Sorry for trying to be helpful.